# iOS 5 newsstand application icon

Tags: newsstand-kit

```
<key>UINewsstandApp</key>
<true/>
<key>UINewsstandIcon</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>images/AppIcon-114.png</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I have an image located in images/AppIcon-114.png and it doesn't load this icon in the newsstand for my application. It shows the default paper like icon.

What is the path relative to?

Comment: if you temporarily put your png icons into the main folder (i.e. same level as the images folder), and modify the string array in the plist, does that fix the problem?

Comment: No, it still displays the default icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did a quick test. In my project I put the icon files in the main app directory, where main.m resides. They are called Icon.png and Icon@2x.png for the application icons, and Newsstand-Cover-Icon.png and Newsstand-Cover-Icon@2x.png

The CFBundleIcons section of the *.plist file (found in the main app directory) looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon.png</string>
            <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>UINewsstandIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Newsstand-Cover-Icon.png</string>
            <string>Newsstand-Cover-Icon@2x.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UINewsstandBindingType</key>
        <string>UINewsstandBindingTypeMagazine</string>
        <key>UINewsstandBindingEdge</key>
        <string>UINewsstandBindingEdgeLeft</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Other relevant sections of the *.plist file are set to this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>newsstand-content</string>
</array>


<key>UINewsstandApp</key>
<true/>
```

You may have to build and launch your app on the device a couple of times, before the icons appear on the Newsstand shelf.

You can edit *.plist files with a text editor like TextWrangler (free), TextMate (paid), or MacVim (free).

Hope this helps!

Comment: What size should "Newsstand-Cover-Icon.png" have?

Answer (score 0):

If it's still displaying the default icon even with the .png files in the right place, something tells me your icons aren't in the proper format (most likely this not the correct size).

Check out the ["App Icons" section of the iOS programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) for the icon sizes.

And also, in the ["Contents of the UINewstandIcon Icon Dictionary" documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW15), it recommends to ***not*** use the extension (i.e. get rid of the `.png` bit in the plist's array).

Comment: I can get my application icon to display, but what is the difference between that at the newsstand icon. Should I be seeing the newsstand icon instead of the application icon?

Comment: The above comment is confusing. In the newsstand, are you trying to get your application icon to display or a custom icon or?

Comment: Well there are 2 settings:
1. <key>UINewsstandIcon</key>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
   <array>
    <string>icon_newsstand.png</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
2. <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
 <array>
  <string>icon.png</string>
  <string>icon@2x.png</string>
 </array>

Comment: This happened to me too. The keys were right but it seems the simulator does some caching. It showed after the sim. was closed once.